# Is the following definite integral necessarily zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vectors

Is the following definite integral necessarily zero:

> $$\oint_0^{s'}   \oint_0^s \vec{ds} . \vec {ds'}$$
>
> where $s$ and $s'$ are arc lengths of closed curves.

If yes, then for what reason?

Comment: What *means* $\oint_0^s$?

Comment: It means closed line integral of a closed curve from $0$ to $s$

Comment: What **means**  "closed curve from 0 [point] to $s$ [curve]"? A closed curve starts and ends in the same *point*.

Comment: arc length of closed curve $s$

Comment: And what means the 0?

Comment: The point on curve $s$ where $s=0$

Comment: Or the point on curve $s$ from where the arc length begins.

Comment: Yes... closed curve starts and ends at same point. $s=0$ and $s=s$ are same points.

Comment: Then $s$ is the arclength *parameter* and the *curve*?????

Comment: More nonsense: the arrow means usually integral of a *vector field* while your integrand is *scalar* (constant 1).

Answer (score 0):

*Possible* interpretation of your question. If $\gamma$ is a closed curve with arclength parameter $s$,then the line integral of the scalar function $1$
$$\oint_\gamma\,ds$$
is the length of the curve. BTW, $\gamma$ being closed is irrelevant. Integrating this *constant* again along another curve...